# Cartesian Product of a normal set and a set with an element which is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the Cartesian product of A and C?

Where:

**A = {0, 1, {2, 3, 4}}**

**C = {1, 5}**

Pretty standard for the first 2 elements of A.
So far I have **{(0,1), (0,5), (1,1), (1,5).... }**

But for the last element of A, is it **{((2,3,4),1), ((2,3,4),5)}**, or do I have to make a pair for each element in **{2,3,4}**?

Comment: Observe that $\{2,3,4\}$ is an element of $A$.  Therefore you have to treat it like an element.  Therefore, you at least have some ordered pair $(\{2,3,4\}, 1) \in A \times C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get around the confusion. Write $x=\{2,3,4\},$ so that $A=\{0,1,x\}.$

You should easily be able to see that $$A\times C=\bigl\{(0,1),(0,5),(1,1),(1,5),(x,1),(x,5)\bigr\}.$$ Now, replace each instance of $x$ with $\{2,3,4\},$ and you're done.

As a side note, try not to worry too much about sets that have sets as elements--that happens quite a lot.